# Clearing the JavaScript/jQuery Event Queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

We found, during a recent upgrade to Google Chrome (version 55+) where [pointer events](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/pointer-events) were introduced  *"with a newer standard that unifies both models: pointer events."*, we need to modify how we handle events to be backwards compatible. Our application is written specifically for Chrome.

We have been [experimenting](https://jsfiddle.net/97ysrcy3/6/) this morning, trying figure out which event has been fired (based on Chrome version) so we can handle the event appropriately for all of our application's users. As a test I wrote the following:

```
$(document).on('mousedown touchstart pointerdown', '.foo', function(event){
    console.log( event.type + ": " +  event.which );
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'mousedown':
          console.log('moused!');
          break;
        case 'touchstart':
          console.log('touched!');
          break;
        case 'pointerdown':
          console.log('pointed');
          break;    
    };
})
```

In non-mobile devices both `mousedown` and `pointerdown` are registered. In mobile devices all three events are spit out to the console.

**CLARIFICATION**: What is needed is for none of the other events to fire once the first one is encountered and handled. In other words, if `pointerdown` fires, for example, then I need to prevent `mousedown` and `touchstart` from firing. Subsequent clicks should work as well, so if I get a `pointerdown` and click again I should get another `pointerdown` (or whatever event is appropriate for the browser version or device).

I expected `break;` would cause jQuery to leave the `switch()`, but that doesn't happen. So I added the [`.clearQueue()`](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) to each case:

```
$(this).clearQueue();
```

Once again, I expected that the event would be encountered and handled, the queue would be cleared and I wouldn't have any other events fired.

I was wrong.

I am beginning to feel like I am missing something obvious but I cannot put my finger on it. I have tried [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/), [`.finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) as well as combinations of these functions in order to intercept the one function needed (based on browser version) and clear the queue so the rest will not fire.

I thought I understood the JavaScript event queue pretty well, but apparently I am wrong about that too.

Am I missing something obvious? If so, what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `.stop()` and `.finish()` are related to working with an animation queue, not an event queue and `.clearQueue()` is not related to the event queue either:

The [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) says:

> When used without an argument, .clearQueue() removes the remaining
>   functions from fx, the standard effects queue. In this way it is
>   similar to .stop(true). However, while the .stop() method is meant to
>   be used only with animations,  .clearQueue() can also be used to
>   remove any function that has been added to a generic jQuery queue with
>   the .queue() method.

But, if you have handled an event and wish to stop others from being raised, you could implement your own `handled` flag in a closure as a work-around:

Here's an example (executable version **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/qg5jxrsc/4/)**):

```
// These free variables will be shared in the various callback functions below
var handled = false;
var eventType = null;

$(document).on('mousedown touchstart pointerdown', '.foo', function(event){

   // If the current event hasn't been handled or if the current 
   // has been handled but the event is the same as the previous fired 
   // event, proceed:
   if(!handled || (handled && event.type === eventType)){

     // None of the events have been handled yet.
     // Determine which has fired and act appropriately:

     // Register the current event for comparison later
     eventType = event.type;

     console.log( eventType + ": " +  event.which );

     switch(eventType) {
        case 'mousedown':
          console.log('moused!');
          break;
        case 'touchstart':
          console.log('touched!');
          break;
        case 'pointerdown':
          console.log('pointed');
          break;    
     };

     // Flag that one of the events registered earlier has been handled
     handled = true;

   } else {

     // One of the earlier registered events has already been handled

     // Prevent the event from performing its native function
     // (i.e. cancel the event)
     event.preventDefault();

     // Don't allow the event to propagate
     event.stopPropagation();

   }

});
```

Comment: According to what you posted, `.clearQueue()` should work. `.stopPropagation()` does not work. All of the events still fire and each `case` returns its value. This was something I tested early on and even tried placing the `.stopPropagation()` in each `case`, before the `switch` and after the `switch`.

Comment: How do you figure? `clearQueue()` is meant for an effects queue or a custom queue, not an event queue. `.stopPropagation()` will limit the event from bubbling and then being triggered again.

Comment: *"clearQueue() can also be used to remove any function that has been added to a generic jQuery queue with the .queue() method."* Perhaps jQuery doesn't use `.queue()` to add to its own queue's.

Comment: JQuery abstracts standard JavaScript and DOM API's. When you use `queue()`, you are registering your own callbacks, but for event registration `.on(....)`, `.queue()` is not used.

Comment: Fair enough - that explains why the `.clearQueue()` did not work.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer :)

Comment: No it isn't @SamBattat. A quick test reveals that it doesn't work. It only stops the propagation of *each* event. It doesn't stop the other events after, for example, `mousedown` is handled. `pointerdown` still fires.

Comment: Which version of Chrome did you test this on?

Comment: That stops any subsequent event from being handled, so that isn't workable either. When I clicked the first time `pointerdown` registered and nothing else did (**GOOD**) but a subsequent click registered no event at all (**BAD**).

Comment: Ok, I understand you now. Give me a few minutes to re-work this.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I really appreciate your efforts here. My brain is mushy from trying to figure out what to do here.

Comment: Ok, give the latest version a try.

Comment: You caught the syntax error right as I  did! This works perfectly Scott, thank you!

Comment: Yeah AND I just updated my `if` logic. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could just `return false` at the end, and only the first type supported (*and first fired*) will be caught by any system.

The `break` works just fine but it  does not affect this issue as these are different events and so fire the handler as many times as the events triggered.

```js
$(document).on('mousedown touchstart pointerdown', '.foo', function(event){
    console.log( event.type + ": " +  event.which );
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'mousedown':
          console.log('moused!');
          break;
        case 'touchstart':
          console.log('touched!');
          break;
        case 'pointerdown':
          console.log('pointed');
          break;    
    };
    // added the following line which forces any subsequent events for the same action and also stop the event from bubbling up the dom
    return false;
})
```

```css
.foo{
  padding:50px;
  margin:10px;
  border:5px double #ccc;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">.foo box for clicking</div>
```

Comment: This will not stop other events that were triggered from firing. See: https://jsfiddle.net/61vt7t1w/3/ which shows this. `return false` in a JQuery event handler is identical to having `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`, which only intercept one event at a time.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/qg5jxrsc/4/ for my solution and how it differs from what yours does.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are testing for different types of events. The OP was asking for events that fire for the same user action, namely `mousedown`, `touchstart` and `pointerdown`.